# How to get current working directory inside a Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a Cmdlet for PowerShell in C#. I am subclassing a `Cmdlet` and NOT a `PSCmdlet`.

Is there a way to get the current directory from PowerShell? I could do so with the `PSCmdlet` using `GetVariableValue("pwd")`. But in the Cmd class I do not have that available.

`Environment.CurrentDiretory` points me to the path where powershell was started from, not where PowerShell itself is currently positioned.

**edit**

Example:

I fire up powershell via - say - `powershell_ise.exe`. It starts up in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`. I then change path using `cd c:\my\folder` and run my command `Do-Something`. Inside the implementation of "Do-Something" (C#-side) I'd like to be able to retrieve the current path => `c:\my\folder`.

If possible, I would like to avoid using `PSCmdlet`.

Comment: You should really be using `PSCmdlet` or pass the location as parameter argument from the invoking cmdlet.

Comment: I am currently rewriting my code to derive from ``PSCmdlet``. Looks good so far. I was a bit scared of it because I really don't need much of it, except access to it's internals. And on the other hand ... that's exactly what it's for I guess...

Comment: Exactly, you have a runtime dependecy (current location) = use PSCmdlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am starting in `C:\Users\<myusername>`. If I know enter `cd..` I am in `C:\Users\`

Entering `(Get-Location).Path` returns `C:\Users`. Thats what you want, isnt it?

Altrnativly try:

```
WriteObject(this.SessionState.Path.CurrentFileSystemLocation);
```

Reference: [How can I get the current directory in PowerShell cmdlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897918/how-can-i-get-the-current-directory-in-powershell-cmdlet)

Comment: I updated my original answer with an example. I would like to avoid running further cmdlets to get my current path. Unless I have no other way.

Comment: @Hemisphera I've updated my answer. I don't have access to LinqPad or Visual Studio right now, so I can't confirm this works,

Comment: It only works because I now use ``PSCmdlet``. ``Cmdlet`` alone does not provide access to ``SessionState``. But since I ended up using ``PSCmdlet`` I'll mark this as answered. It's cleaner than ``GetVariableValue("pwd")`` anway. Thanks!